# Remove an SVG element after animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, raphael

So for my assignment I have a webpage where I input a number and choose a shape and the chosen number amount of the chosen shape will appear and go through a set animation. After the animation, I need to make the shape disappear. I've tried everything including using the remove() action and still can't figure this one out.

So here's my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o6e2yu5b/2/

Here's the javascript code:

```
draw = function() {
  var typed = $('#howmany').val()
  var shape = $('#shape').val()
  var x, y;

  for (var i = 0; i < typed; i++) {
    x = Math.random() * 350
    y = Math.random() * 350
    if (shape == 'a') {
      pattern = paper.circle(25, 25, 25)
    }
    if (shape == 'b') {
      pattern = paper.rect(10, 10, 50, 50)
    }
    if (shape == 'c') {
      pattern = paper.path('M25,0 L50,50, L0,50 Z')
    }

    color_attr = {
        'fill': '#BB7'
    }

    position_attr = {
      'transform': 't' + x + ',' + y
    }

    pattern.attr(color_attr)
    pattern.animate(position_attr, 2000)
        onComplete:function() {
        this.target.remove();
    }
  }
}

setup = function() {
  paper = Raphael('svg1', 400, 400)
  $('button').click(draw)
}
jQuery(document).ready(setup)
```

Please help! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your onComplete function is incorrect and didn't work. So I made a new setTimeout function that will delete generated shape/s after animation is complete. Check out this demo https://jsfiddle.net/o6e2yu5b/3/

```
setTimeout(function(){
  SVG.find("circle").remove();
  SVG.find("rect").remove();
  SVG.find("path").remove();
}, 2000);
```